# PHP - Black image detection and Ignore text. How?

Tags: php, text, timestamp

My security cam has a failure, sometimes at the movement, the first snaps are black. That’s not a really a problem but I was looking for a way to delete those black images via a PHP script.

This one works great with a fully black images:

```
<?php
function check_if_black($src){

   $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    list($width_orig, $height_orig)=getimagesize($src);
    for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
        $rand_width=rand ( 0 , $width_orig );
        $rand_height=rand ( 0 , $height_orig );
        $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $rand_width, $rand_height);
        if($rgb!=0){
            return "not black";
        }
    }
    return "black";
}
?>
```

My snaps have a white timestamp on it. Always in the same position and always with white text. With the code I posted above it says the image isn't black. But `80%` of it is. Is there a way to detect if the snapshot is black and ignores the white timestamp on it?

A sample of a snapshot:
[image: Sample screenshot]

Comment: Please use unlink($src) function to delete file or image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the timestamp will be placed at the bottom of the image means, you may ignore some height in the bottom and then take the image width and height. Now you will have only the black image

```
function check_if_black($src){

   $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    list($width_orig, $height_orig)=getimagesize($src);
    $height_orig=$height_orig-20;//Reduce some height(Ex 20px) here
    for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
        $rand_width=rand ( 0 , $width_orig );
        $rand_height=rand ( 0 , $height_orig );
        $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $rand_width, $rand_height);
        if($rgb!=0){
            return "not black";
        }
    }
    return "black";
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. It ignores the timestamp and detects black images. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your problem, you just need to call `check_if_black($src)` function check if it returns black then use `unlink()` function to delete this image.

```
<?php
function check_if_black($src){

   $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    list($width_orig, $height_orig)=getimagesize($src);
    for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
        $rand_width=rand ( 0 , $width_orig );
        $rand_height=rand ( 0 , $height_orig );
        $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $rand_width, $rand_height);
        if($rgb!=0){
            return "not black";
        }
    }
    return "black";
}

// $src is iamge path

    $resp = check_if_black($src);
    if($resp=='black'){
     unlink($src);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know how to delete the image. The problem is that the snapshot isn't detected as black because the white timestamp on it. I want to ignore the timestamp.